# Steps in simplifying fractions with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, fractions

I'm going through a discrete math program, and it's been quite a long time since I took algebra. As a result, I'm having difficulty understanding the steps of how my instructor came up with this result for the below equation. Can anyone help walk me through the steps?

$\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1} + \frac{(r^{n+1})(r -1)}{r-1}$

$= \frac{r^{n+2}-1}{r-1}$

Comment: You should review basic exponent laws and how to add fractions. This was just basic addition and simplification. No complicated steps required.

Comment: Thanks, I plan to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}+\frac{(r^{n+1})(r-1)}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}+\frac{(r^{n+1}r)-(r^{n+1}1)}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}+\frac{r^{n+2}-r^{n+1}}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{r^{n+1}-1+r^{n+2}-r^{n+1}}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{r^{n+1}-r^{n+1}+r^{n+2}-1}{r-1}$$
$$=\frac{r^{n+2}-1}{r-1}$$